# R shinydashboardPlus - make the pretty switch pretty again

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

Using shinydashboardPlus with prettySwitch in the right sidebar - the alignment of the switch elements are messed up

[image: ugly switch]

Is there a way to make the switch pretty again like this

[image: pretty switch]

Here is the code.  Setting md = FALSE will work, but will affect the look of everything else, so I don't want to do that.

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dashboardHeaderPlus(
    enable_rightsidebar = TRUE
  )
  , dashboardSidebar()
  , dashboardBody()
  , rightSidebar(
    background = "light"
    , rightSidebarTabContent(
      id = "id"
      , title = "title"
      , prettySwitch(
        inputId = "switch_id"
        , label = "switch"
      )
    )
  )
  , md = TRUE
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, I can't find `dashboardSidebar()` from `shinydashboardPlus`, where it came from ?

Comment: It was from `shinydashboard`

Answer (score 1):

There's a CSS conflict with Material Design theme, to fix it, you can add the following CSS code into your application :

```
  , tags$style(HTML(
    ".pretty > div > label {font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 1px !important;}"
  ))
```

Above `prettySwitch` for example

Answer (score 0):

Even not elegant way, but you could adjust it by modify `CSS`

[image]

Comment: That's a good start - can you get the ball into the oval too?